# Can't get variables from other php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code in `index.php`

```
<?php
include "ch.php";
?>

ch.php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Murad'])) {
    header("Location: Main.php");
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $userName=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['pwd1'];
    $userName = stripslashes($userName);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $userName = mysql_real_escape_string($userName);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "123";
    $mysql_databse = "websiteusers";
    $prefix = "";
    $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO websiteusers 
        (fullname,lastname,userName,email,pass) 
        VALUES ( '$firstname', '$lastname','$userName', '$email','$password')
    ";
    mysql_select_db('websiteusers');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql );
    if (! $retval ) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        return false;
    } else {
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
    }
    $usernamecheck=mysql_query("
        SELECT `userName` FROM `websiteusers` 
        WHERE userName='$userName'
    ");
    if (mysql_num_rows($usernamecheck)>=1) {
        echo $userName." is already taken";
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

And

```
Main.PHP

<?php
include 'ch.php';
?>
```

And

```
<?php  
  echo $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
?>
```

But it is not working.  It worked before I put action in form instead of header but it didn't insert user in database now it inserts but it is not showing variables.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: There's a lot of errors. The major ones are: The `mysql_real_escape_string()` works only after the connection with the db and the `header("Location: Main.php");` in that position bypass all the script below. Furthermore you can't pass a POST variable with the `header("Location: Main.php");`.

Comment: @MaveriCk But when i use action in form it is not adding user in dt

Comment: header("Location: Main.php"); ??? without any processing, forwarding to main.php page??

Comment: header("Location: Main.php"); cause that.

Comment: **1)** Do not use `mysql_` functions, it's deprecated and will be removed at PHP 7 stable release, choose between [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). **2)** Don't open and close your php interpreter multiple times with no apparent reason. If your code is pure PHP, a standard is to never close it. **3)** There should be nothing else for PHP or HTML to be processed/displayed after using [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)("Location: ...") function. It's the last thing you do at the script when you use it.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale Thanks! I just needed to put header at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Do not use `mysql_` functions, it's deprecated and will be removed at PHP 7 stable release, choose between [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**2)** Don't open and close your php interpreter multiple times with no apparent reason. If your code is pure PHP, a standard is to never close it.

**3)** There should be nothing else for PHP or HTML to be processed/displayed after using [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)`("Location: ...")` function. It's the last thing you do at the script when you use it.